# Pandas: how to add a column with a value depending on subsequent rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe.

```
timestamp   close   open    high    low volume  datetime    candlestick_pattern candlestick_match_count SYMBOL
0   510037200   0.095486    0.088542    0.103299    0.088542    1857052800  1986-03-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
1   512715600   0.111979    0.095486    0.121962    0.092882    547142400   1986-04-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
2   515304000   0.121528    0.111979    0.123264    0.107639    333446400   1986-05-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
3   517982400   0.106771    0.121528    0.121528    0.102431    293788800   1986-06-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
4   520574400   0.098958    0.106771    0.109375    0.090278    460800000   1986-07-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
5   523252800   0.098958    0.098958    0.106771    0.094618    266256000   1986-08-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
6   525931200   0.098090    0.098958    0.109375    0.091146    285120000   1986-09-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
7   528523200   0.134549    0.098090    0.139757    0.095486    1565712000  1986-10-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
8   531205200   0.172743    0.135417    0.177951    0.135417    1053964800  1986-11-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
9   533797200   0.167535    0.172743    0.173611    0.157118    721526400   1986-12-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
10  536475600   0.253906    0.167535    0.269097    0.164931    1961596800  1987-01-01 05:00:00 CDLHIKKAKE_Bear 1.0 MSFT
11  539154000   0.266493    0.253906    0.276042    0.230903    1834272000  1987-02-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
12  541573200   0.335938    0.266493    0.343750    0.255208    1783324800  1987-03-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
13  544251600   0.361111    0.335938    0.378472    0.314236    2118585600  1987-04-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
14  546840000   0.400174    0.361111    0.445312    0.356771    2192054400  1987-05-01 04:00:00 CDLBELTHOLD_Bull    1.0 MSFT
15  549518400   0.354167    0.400174    0.400174    0.334201    1729353600  1987-06-01 04:00:00 CDLBELTHOLD_Bear    1.0 MSFT
16  552110400   0.326389    0.353299    0.367188    0.307292    1813536000  1987-07-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
17  554788800   0.412326    0.326389    0.421007    0.316840    2034921600  1987-08-01 04:00:00 CDLMORNINGSTAR_Bull 2.0 MSFT
18  557467200   0.460069    0.409722    0.462674    0.368056    1554902400  1987-09-01 04:00:00 CDLCLOSINGMARUBOZU_Bull 1.0 MSFT
19  560059200   0.345486    0.460069    0.550347    0.258681    3567219200  1987-10-01 04:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
20  562741200   0.310764    0.342014    0.361111    0.281250    1550172800  1987-11-01 05:00:00 NO_PATTERN  0.0 MSFT
21  565333200   0.376736    0.309028    0.388889    0.277778    1780182400  1987-12-01 05:00:00 CDLENGULFING_Bull   1.0 MSFT
22  568011600   0.387153    0.380208    0.428819    0.364583    1966780800  1988-01-01 05:00:00 CDL3OUTSIDE_Bull    7.0 MSFT
```

I need to add 2 columns:
Increased 5% in the next 3 rows.
This should be 0 or 1 depending if the CLOSE column of the next 3 rows increased 5%. The code should only work for the rows which have a pattern with the 'BULL' word in it.

The 2nd column, should be the actual percentage it increased in the next 3 rows.

Obviously, this wont be possible to calculate for the last 3 rows of the pandas data frame, so the code needs to handle this.

Update:

1. In the future the dataframe will have all stocks, not just MSFT
2. 5% from the current to the third next row!

Comment: Hi Luis, when you say increased 5% in the next 3 rows, do you mean that any of the 3 rows should be 5% higher? Or the row 3 rows from current should be 5% higher?

Comment: Other question: I think you want this per stock? Or is there only 1 stock in your dataframe? Can you update the question with this info?

Comment: just dit, I hope its clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important in the solution here is the use of:

- `.shift(-3)` to look 3 days ahead
- combined with `.groupby('SYMBOL')['close'].transform()` to do this within a group of the same stock for every row in the dataframe

Docs on .shift():
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Docs on .groupby().transform():
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html

```py
# taking subset just to keep better overview of what's happening
# the sorting is important for future calculations
df_subset = df[
    ['SYMBOL', 'datetime', 
     'close', 'candlestick_pattern']
].sort_values(by=['SYMBOL', 'datetime'])

# check what the future value will be within the SYMBOL group. Use shift(-3) to look 3 ahead.
df_subset['shift_3_rows_ahead'] = (df_subset
    .groupby('SYMBOL')['close']
    .transform(lambda x: x.shift(-3)))

# calculate percentage increase
df_subset['perc_increase'] = (
    (df_subset['shift_3_rows_ahead'] 
    / df_subset['close'] - 1) * 100)

# check if percentage increase is > 5 percent
df_subset['increase_larger_than_5_percent'] = df_subset['perc_increase'] > 5.

# check if relevant column contains the word bull
df_subset['contains_bull'] = df_subset['candlestick_pattern'].str.contains('bull', case=False)

# check if column contains bull and if the future increase is > 5%
df_subset['should_be_looked_at'] = (
    df_subset['contains_bull'] 
    & df_subset['increase_larger_than_5_percent']
)
```